# App Engine - Google Cloud SQL - Local MySQL database for jUnit - rdbms package not found

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, junit, google-cloud-sql

The offline database in MySQL is working fine when i launch the app but i would like to make it work also for my unit testing!

But it tells me that the "**rdbms**" package is missing.

May be am i'm missing an import or something because i got the following Exception :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Exception = com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'rdbms' or call 'OpenConnection()' was not found.
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at testDb.DbUserUnitTestCase.testAdd(DbUserUnitTestCase.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Looks like i'm not the only one have the trouble too:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/gyIOtJSrRkY
- http://googlecloudsql.blogspot.com/2012/03/unit-testing-google-cloud-sql-with.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/VOMSNqn2FWI/bNf5pmqvDQUJ
  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i'm gonna respond to my own question, i found a work around doing this

```
    if(isUnitTesting) {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root","");

    } else {

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://"+instanceName+"/project");

    }
```

Not the best way i guess so feel free to respond if you have a better answer!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I had this same problem and was finally able to get it to work. Here is a summary of the issue:

1. The com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver driver ONLY works if you are running within actual App Engine, or in the local App Engine dev environment. It does NOT work (gives this "rdbms" package missing error) when you are running just in unit tests or outside of App Engine. This is true even if you set the rdbms.driver system property to something else.
2. The driver that DOES work in a non-App Engine java process is com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.
3. Unfortunately, things get tricky if you are using DriverManager.getConnection() to load the driver (which most datasources do). This method looks at registered drivers to see which one can load the supplied URL. Thus, you'll get into trouble if you register BOTH AppEngineDriver and com.google.cloud.sql.Driver - the "wrong one" may get used when you are loading a jdbc:google:rdbms DB URL.

In my case, I am using maven, Spring and iBatis. My solution is that when running test cases I use Spring's SimpleDriverDataSource. This data source let's you use an ACTUAL driver instance, instead of just specifying the class name. That means you don't have to worry about having both AppEngineDriver and com.google.cloud.sql.Driver in your classpath:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.google.cloud.sql.Driver"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="jdbc:google:rdbms://myProject:myInstance/myDb"/>
</bean>
```

Also, note that com.google.cloud.sql.Driver doesn't appear to be packaged in any of the standard maven artifacts. Instead, it comes in the appengine-java-sdk at appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3/lib/impl/google_sql.jar. For me, there was other stuff in google_sql.jar that was colliding with other dependencies I have (some jackson libraries), so instead I pulled out just the com.google packages into a separate jar. I then added this jar to my dependencies in maven as explained here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies. I then added this as a dependency to my project with test scope.

Comment: com.google.cloud.sql.Driver - ClassNotFoundException. And i do not see it in appengine-api-x.x-sdk-x.x.x.x.jar